# Visual studio 2017: QT Add-in

Tags: visual-studio, qt, add-in, visual-studio-2017, qt5.8

I've installed Visual Studio 2017 and QT 5.8.

Now I installed a QT-Add-in(from [here](http://download.qt.io/development_releases/vsaddin/)) and I wanted to add the Path of QT 5.8 in Qt Options(in Visual Studio).

But I get an error like : "This QT version uses an unsupported makefile generator (used: MINGW, supported: MSVN.NET, MSBUILD)"

Is there a workaround or a way to fix this problem ?

Comment: You have probably installed Qt build with GCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Qt that you're attempting to use has not been compiled with a binary-compatible compiler - either Visual Studio 2015 or Visual Studio 2017. You'll have to download Qt for MSVC2015, or build it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The think problem lies with what package you installed. I found, after I downloaded the add-in and downloaded the binaries, that I had downloaded the wrong binaries. What I did to fix the problem is I deleted my current installation of QT and reinstalled them (using QT's online installer) after unchecking the default MinGW binaries and checking the box for MSVC-2017-x64. [Here is a picture, if that helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYHKi.png)
After installing that, I was able to correctly add the binaries to the path.

Answer (score 1):

The Qt Visual Studio Tools for VS2017 is now in Beta:
https://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/08/03/qt-visual-studio-tools-version-2-1-2-beta/

It will be updated through the Visual Studio Marketplace from now on.

Answer (score 0):

My friend was suffering with qt because it does not work with visual studio 2017, today 08/14/2017 I downloaded the free version online, and in the components I unchecked MinGW and marked MSVC 2017 (But it only has the 64 bit version when I downloaded it today ).

Installation occurred normally and the result was this:

[image: Simples teste com o qt utilizando o MSVC 2017]

I wish good luck with your project, the version of qt I am using is 5.9.1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get v2.2 to work on VS2017. However, when I closed Visual Studio and opened it up again, it did not work anymore. This is because VS upgraded the app to version 2.3 which did not work.  I uninstalled 2.3, re-installed 2.2 and uncheck the auto update check box.