# Visual Studio 2017 QT: No default QT version found

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2017, qt-vs-addin

Working with Windows 7,
installed VS 2017 community,
Installed QT Visual Studio Tools,
Downloaded QT: "qt-opensource-windows-x86-winrt-msvc2015-5.8.0"
and added the path of winrt_x86_msvc2015 and winrt_x64_msvc2015.

When i start a new project "QT GUI Application" and click on the *.ui file, then the error message "No default QT version found. Check your Qt VS Tools settings." appears.

What did i do wrong? 
Is the QT Download the right one? If not can you link the right?
which version is actually the right? x86 or x64?
Do i have to change something in Qt default settings?

Comment: That tools is for visual studio 2015, it is not for visual studio 2017: qt-opensource-windows-x86-winrt-**msvc2015**-5.8.0

Comment: well and is there a tool for vs2017? I found nothing. A link would be awesome.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287471/visual-studio-2017-qt-add-in

Comment: I read the discussion you linked. The solution of the guy with visual studio 2017 was, to use the online installer of QT. The Problem is that this installer doesn't work for me, because i always loose connection to the server.. However, i asked now directly in qt-forum for a solution...thanks

Comment: hi, have you solved it? my env is win64bit with **qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.9.2**, **msvc2017**, and **qt-vsaddin-msvc2017-2.2.1_48f558a.vsix installed**, and I just bumped into this problem at my first opened GUIApplication, it popped out an warning window as you mentioned. Then I went to **qtvstools**> **qt** options and found out there's no qt version filled on that table. I filled them in, linked with the right path and it worked now. hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

In VS2017, at the top menu I had to choose:

```
Qt VS Tools > Qt Options
```

The entry list may be empty.

```
Click "Add"
Give it a name
Give it a path
```

i.e.

```
 Name:  Qt5.8
 Path:  C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015_64
```

Now, you can right-click the Solution

```
    Choose > "Change Qt Version" at the bottom of the right-click dialogue
    Select your new entry "Qt5.8"
```